# hdfs is not accessible by hduser, hadoop installation

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I am installing Hadoop 2.6.4 on Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is when I switch to hduser and do not get the hdfs:

```
su - hduser 
ssh localhost
hduser>hdfs 
No command 'hdfs' found, did you mean:
Command 'hfs' from package 'hfsutils-tcltk' (universe)
Command 'hdfls' from package 'hdf4-tools' (universe)
hdfs: command not found
```

but when I do not switch to hduser, I got the full access:

```
 mylaptop>hdfs 
 Usage: hdfs [--config confdir] COMMAND
 where COMMAND is one of:dfs         
 run a filesystem command on the file systems supported in Hadoop. 
 ....
```

I have checked the settings, everything seems to be fine. Is it a problem if I do not use hduser!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each user having its own bashrc file
so you have to set hadoop home and java home in hduser bashrc file
once you login to hduser please set $HADOOP_HOME,  $JAVA_HOME & bin path

```
    #Set HADOOP_HOME
    export HADOOP_HOME=/pathtohadoop/hadoop-2.7.2
    #Set JAVA_HOME
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
    # Add bin/ directory of Hadoop to PATH
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```